# converting mysql_query into mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have been working on a project for one of my clients.
i used mysql_query but recently i noticed that "mysql_query" will no longer be on php 7.
now i need to convert my queries quickly because i should finish the project.
is there any way to easily just convert the "mysql_queries" to mysqli?
will this work?

```
mysql_query("insert into ...");
```

convert to:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
$mysqli->query("insert into ...");
```

if yes, can i just use search and replace in notepad++ to convert all queries(insert,update,delete)?

Comment: SQL statements did not change, only extensions did. If you follow PHP MySQLi manual page you'll see key differences in examples. Yes, you can look them up with notepad++ but never replace them automatically, be cautious.

Comment: just do it slow and methodically. A lot has changed, like parameters, error reporting, to do it right, throughout. If you want to just put lipstick on a pig, do it your way

Comment: I would say would be better to use a macro for such type of changes. In vim it is a simple search and replace.

Comment: @DeDee @drew @georoot guys why i can't just use search and replace? if the example i write was right, i can do that: find `mysql_query` replace with: `$mysqli->query` you think it can cause problem? (the queries are mostly just basic, just simple insert,update and delete.